# Remove last comma during an explode in PHP

Tags: php

How to ignore the last comma inserted ?

```
<?php
$moods = "pizza1,pizza2,pizza3,";
$moodList = explode(",", $moods);
print_r($moodList);
?>
```

Comment: `$moodList = explode(",", trim($moods, ','));`

Comment: `$moodList = array_filter($moodList);` But `trim()` before is more efficient.

Answer (score 7):

```
$moodlist = explode(',',trim($moods,','));
```

Just trim commas.

Comment: I see @Mark Baker already suggested this in the comments. I see no reason why you would use more cumbersome strlen methods, unless you *really* want to keep any commas that appear at the front of your list. `trim` will remove both

Comment: Only difference between Mark's answer and mine is my use of single quotes around the first comma, which will make my code execute several nanoseconds faster.

Comment: That several nanoseconds faster is actually a myth, if you look at the actual opcodes generated, unless you're actively interjecting variables into the quoted string

Comment: Ahh, so you're saying that double quotes are just as fast as single quotes unless there is a variable between the double quotes? I thought PHP had to "check and see" if any variables were there. Not that those nanoseconds are even worth the hours spent discussing them anyway.

Comment: Even single quoted strings have to be parsed to check for escaped characters (e.g. `\'`), so unless there's interpolation necessary, they both need parsing

Answer (score 0):

How about using `substr()` to cut out the last comma?

```
// Your string
$str = "pizza1,pizza2,pizza3,";
// The $num is the string length, minus 1 (b/c you're cutting the last character out in substr)
$num = strlen($str) - 1;
// Cut the last character with substr
$edited_str = substr($str, 0, $num);
// The result
echo $edited_str;
```

**EDIT**

As Mark Baker has pointed out, you can simply use `$str = substr($str, 0, -1);` instead of counting the string length. So

```
// Your string
$str = "pizza1,pizza2,pizza3,";
// Cut the last character with substr
$edited_str = substr($str, 0, -1);
// The result
echo $edited_str;
```

Comment: If you really want to use substr(), use `$str = substr($str, 0, -1);` because there's no need to use strlen() at all, making it faster and easier

Answer (score 0):

You Can Ignore it like this

```html
<?php
$moods = "pizza1,pizza2,pizza3,";
$moodList = explode(",", substr($moods,0,strlen($moods)-1));
print_r($moodList);
?>
```